# Customizing Controls in Smash Bros Wii U (for Smash Mode)

Tags: super-smash-bros-4, keyboard

I set up a profile for custom controls and saved it. When I play training mode, I can click on my name and then choose my profile from a drop down list of existing controls profiles. So far so good.

But it seems I cannot choose my profile when I play Smash Mode: the drop down list does not appear! If I click on my player name, it only switches between "player 1", "COM" and "empty".

Am I doing something wrong? Does anyone else have this problem? I'm playing the German version of Smash Bros Wii U.

EDIT: It seems it is not possible to change the user name in every mode. In training mode, it is possible, as well as in classic smash mode (the one with the board and the trophies on it). I can choose my profile there. And when I do, I can go back to the main menu, then to smash (the biggest button), and then when I choose a character, it is automatically set to the profile I chose in the other modes.

But is there any shortcut for this? It is quite cumbersome to always go to some play mode I never play, choose my profile there, and go back to the mode I want to play...

Comment: I am not the biggest genius with Smash, but I think training doesn't support custom controls. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Smash mode as in a standard 4 (or 8) player battle?